# Populate JQuery Auto-complete from C# dictionary in MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dictionary that Im passing to the ViewModel that my view is using, however I'm trying to map this dictionary to the JQuery Auto-complete so the textbox can get the key and the value but I can't figure it out yet, here is the code :

//here is my text-box

```
<input type="text" Id="NewProxy" value="" />
```

//here the JS code:

```
$(function () {

var response = '@Html.Raw(Model.Dictionary1)';


            $( "#NewProxy" ).autocomplete({
                //  source: response,
                source:[{
                    label: '@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.Dictionary1.Select(i => "'" + i.Value + "'")))',
                    value: '@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.Dictionary1.Select(i => "'" + i.Key + "'")))'
                }]
            });

        });
```

Please note that I don't want to post back for an Ajax Call to get the result as JSON, I already have the data and I want to map it locally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data on the client, you could load the key-value pairs into an array and add them to the input that way. But, I'm just a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of searching and trying, I found out that we can construct an array of objects and each object has to have label and value as per jquery documentation, so the working code is like this:

```
 <input type="text" Id="NewProxy" value="" />

<script>
 $(function () {
          // var response = '@Html.Raw(Model.Dictionary1)';

           // alert(response);

            //form an array of Label and Value from the Dictionary
            var _source = [];
            @foreach (var item in Model.Dictionary1)
            {
            <text>
            _source.push({

                label:'@item.Value',
                value:'@item.Key'


            });
            </text>
            }
            alert(_source);



            $("#NewProxy" ).autocomplete({
                 source: _source

            });



        });
</script>
```

Hope that would help anybody who faces the same issue, and there wasn't very helpful things to solve it on the web!